# MVC Razor display template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, display-templates

I have a list of items that I am passing to a view. I would like to render each item using a display template. However, something is wrong, as I don't get the field properly rendered.
Here is my main view (Index.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomEntity>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m)
```

Here is my display template:

```
@model CustomEntity
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Name):
    <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Icon):
    <strong>@Model.Icon</strong>
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.TypeName):
    <strong>@Model.TypeName</strong>
</div>
```

The page loads, but doesn't display the values of the entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomEntity>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

and then make sure that your display template is stored in `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/CustomEntity.cshtml`. Notice that the location and the name of the display template is very important. It should be called the same way as the type (`CustomEntity.cshtml`) and should be located either in `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` or you could also override it in `~/Views/XXX/DisplayTemplates` where `XXX` is the controller that rendered the main view.

Comment: Won't it search for a DisplayTemplate taking a `IEnumerable<CustomEntity>` as model, instead of `CustomEntity` ?

Comment: Thank you Darin! I was missing the proper name for my display template. It was called Entity instead of CustomEntity. Once I changed the name, it's working. Can you tell me the difference between @Html.DisplayForModel() and @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m) ?

Comment: @RédaMattar, no, when you pass an `IEnumerable<TModel>` as a property to a display or editor template it will look for a template named `TModel.cshtml` and it will automatically invoke it for each element of this collection so that you don't need to be writing any `foreach` loops in your code. It all works by convention.

Comment: @laconicdev, there's no difference between `@Html.DisplayForModel()` and `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m)`. It's just that `@Html.DisplayForModel()` seems more natural in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The data you pass in the `Html.DisplayFor` of type `IEnumerable<CustomEntity>`, but your DisplayTemplate requires a `CustomEntity`. Try this instead :

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomEntity>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach(var customEntity in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => customEntity);
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the foreach loop. MVC handles it by convention so long as everything else is correct.