# How to format string property in MVC model class to be used in DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, string-formatting, displayformat

Okay, I have been looking for a resolution for this simple task all day.

I have an mvc model class which has a BIC property and a NationalNumber property. Bother are **string** values.
I want to use a DisplayFor helper to render the property on the view BUT, with a formatting applied.

for completeness: the formatting for the NationalNumber is '00.00.00-000.00' , the formatting for BIC is AAAA BB CC

I tried annotating my properties with a **DisplayFormat** Attribute, but that only seems to work with DateTimes, numeric values, etc,..

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:##.##.##-###.##}")]
```

Then I looked at [creating a custom DisplayFormat attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778661/displayformatattribute-to-custom-format-a-string), but that also works with patterns that apply to DateTimes, numeric values, etc.. You still need to suppy a **DataFormatString** value in the constructor of your custom attribute. But the filter does not seem to work with strings!

For the moment I ended up doing the markup clientSide(with a mask plugin) but that's not really what I want!

To summarize: I want to use `@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.BicNumber)` and have it rendered with a custom formatting, preferrably annotaded on my viewmodel, with BicNumber being a string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is DisplayFormat DataFormatString not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697872/why-is-displayformat-dataformatstring-not-working)

Comment: have you checked the MSDN documentation on this as well ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have you tried creating a property in your model to return those fields in their proper formats?

Comment: @DJKRAZE It is not a duplicate. `DisplayFormat` never worked for strings in the first place.

Comment: it's marked as possible duplicate not explicit duplicate.. also I am not sure why the op can't use string.format function along with `string.Format("{0:##.##.##-###.##}", what ever value needs to be formatted)`

Comment: @DJKRAZE Because format specifiers do not work with string arguments.

Comment: Trust me I read the documentation very well but they all seem to work for doubles, ints, long, datetime, etc.. but not for strings. Also I checked stackoverflow for similar issues but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 2):

If your `NationalNumber` and `BIC` were separate data types, you could [create display templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19568779/11683), store them under `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/NationalNumber.cshtml` and `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/BIC.cshtml`, and it would then automatically work as you want.

If you want to keep these properties as strings, the automatic approach won't work for you because a display template created for `string.cshtml` would affect all strings in the project.

So create a display template named `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/NationalNumber.cshtml`, where you would manually output parts of the number:

```
@model string
@String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}-{3}.{4}", Model.Substring(0, 2), Model.Substring(2, 2), Model.Substring(4, 2), Model.Substring(6, 3), Model.Substring(9, 2))
```

(note the capitalized `String`, [it is important](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15544173/11683)) and specify it explicitly:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.NationalNumber, "NationalNumber")
```

Comment: I would add the the only option available in Format Strings for String data type is the alignment, that's why DataFormatString does not work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is actually a good approach I never thought about but I would like to abstract this logic in our custom framework so that we can re-use the formatting across all of our projects. With your approach we would have to pack this into a nuget or something to get this to work in every project. I was thinking more like a Formatter attribute for my model.